# Верстка текста из psd

Tags: html, css, photoshop, psd

Предположим у верстальщика есть задание сверстать страницу из **psd**, задачу упростим: предположим ему осталось только форматировать текст. Меня всегда терзал вопрос, как это сделать? 
 Ведь возможности **фотошопа** огромны, почти безграничны, а **html** страница всего лишь ограничивается 15ю стилями **css**, связанных с форматированием (color,font-family, font-size, font-style, font-variant, font-weight, letter-spacing,line-height, text-align, text-indent, text-decoration, text-transform,text-shadow,white-space, word-spacing).
Причем все эти стили примитивны. Например, что такое тень в css? Это смещение по X, Y, цвет и размытость. А в photoshop тень- это свойство с кучей параметров.
Я так же понимаю, что photoshop это мощный редактор изображений, а css это просто скудные стили отображения.
Вопрос следующий: как выкручивается верстальщик в таком случае? (замена всего текста картинкой не лучший вариант)
P.S. Привел пример того, как, предположим, нужно форматировать текст из psd (psd прикрепил)
https://cloud.mail.ru/public/4VGh/LL2xbzmBc

Comment: Мне кажется это больше похоже на опросник, вот если бы вы спросили как сверстать сложную тень и предложили начальный вариант это был бы хороший вопрос. Ну а верстка по проектам в PSD уходит в прошлое, все же с интерактивными элементами и анимацией лучше работать сразу, а вместо подробного макета использовать прототипы и эскизы.

Comment: @ilya-direct: `А в photoshop тень- это свойство с кучей параметров. `


И немасштабируемый растр.